# Operations within group when GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

The key of table *items* is comprised of (*lang*, *id*). Some items have a translated name in different languages. I want to create such a query that would return all the items from the DB in a given language and if an item doesn't have a translation to return the untranslated value.

Say I want to get all items written in Bulgarian. This is where I'm stuck:

```
SELECT lang, id, name
FROM items
WHERE lang = "bg" OR lang = "en"
GROUP BY id
```

The problem arises when there is an item, say, (*1*, *"en"*) and an item (*1*, *"bg"*). The ids are the same. Then how does MySQL or SQLite determine which result to return? Is there any way I can tell it that I would rather prefer to return (*1*, *"bg"*) if it exists but if it doesn't then (*1*, *"en"*) would satisfy me?

**P.S.**
To further illustrate what I want let's imagine that the database contains the following entries with schema (id, lang, name):

(*1*, *"en"*, *"abc"*)

(*2*, *"en"*, *"cde"*)

(*3*, *"en"*, *"def"*)

(*1*, *"bg"*, *"абв"*)

(*3*, *"bg"*, *"жзи"*)

After executing the desired query for Bulgarian I should get:

(*1*, *"bg"*, *"абв"*)

(*2*, *"en"*, *"cde"*)

(*3*, *"bg"*, *"жзи"*)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If "untranslated" means "English" or in other words, the base language is English, you can `LEFT` join the table to itself and use `COALESCE()` function to get rid of `NULL` values

```
SELECT COALESCE(bg.lang, en.lang) AS lang
     , en.id                      AS id
     , COALESCE(bg.name, en.name) AS name
FROM items en
  LEFT JOIN items bg
    ON  bg.id = en.id
    AND bg.lang = 'bg'
WHERE en.lang = 'en'
```

Answer (score 1):

Standard SQL does not let you select columns in "group by" queries that do not either (1) appear on the group by list, or (2) included in an aggregate function. Any industrial strength SQL engine (DB2, Oracle, SQL Server) would consider your query incorrect.

In cases when you need to choose a specific item or a default when it is not in the database, the [coalesce](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html) function is used. With this function in hand, you should be able to formulate your query without "group by".

Comment: Actually standard SQL-2003 allows to be included in SELECT (3): columns functionally dependent on the GROUP BY columns: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7594865/why-does-mysql-add-a-feature-that-conflicts-with-sql-standards/7596265#7596265

Comment: The OP's query though, would still be invalid, even with that standard.

Answer (score 0):

You can do `GROUP BY` on multiple columns:

```
SELECT lang, id, name
FROM items
WHERE lang = "bg" OR lang = "en"
GROUP BY id, lang
```

Comment: I know, but that would return both (*1*, *"bg"*) and (*1*, *"en"*). I actually don't want to have results with mutiple ids.